# How can I check if a ring is contained in another ring using Boost.Geometry?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, boost-geometry

I am trying to determine whether a ring is contained by another ring using the Boost.Geometry library.

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>

using namespace boost::geometry;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    typedef model::d2::point_xy<double> P;
    model::ring<P> ring1, ring2;

    read_wkt("polygon((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0))", ring1);
    read_wkt("polygon((1 1,1 2,2 2,2 1,1 1))", ring2);

    bool b = within(ring1, ring2);
    std::cout << "Within: " << (b ? "YES" : "NO") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it does not compile (with Boost 1.48.0), because it fails a static assertion of `within`:

```
NOT_OR_NOT_YET_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_GEOMETRY_TYPE
```

It seems that `within` only supports checking whether a point is within another geometry (according to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html#geometry.reference.algorithms.within.within_2.supported_geometries)).

I was thinking about treating the rings as linestrings, then check whether they `intersect`, and if not - check if the first point of the ring is within the other ring; but I don't know  if it's possible to avoid copying each `ring` to a `linestring`.

Is there any way to achieve the functionality of `within` for two rings (with reasonable performance)?

Comment: Are you sure "ring" is the right word? These shapes look more like squares.

Comment: A "ring" is essentially a closed geometry (like a polygon) but with no "holes". These geometries are indeed squares.

Comment: I think they actually ment to abbreviate "linear ring", you are right - these are not rings.

Comment: this is still the cast for boost 1.50. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up implementing the idea I suggested in the question:

```
using namespace boost::geometry;

template <typename Point>
bool within(const model::ring<Point>& ring1, const model::ring<Point>& ring2)
{
    return within(ring1.front(), ring2) &&
           disjoint(model::linestring<Point>(ring1.begin(), ring1.end()),
                    model::linestring<Point>(ring2.begin(), ring2.end()));
}
```

Seems to good enough for me, but I'd still be glad to get some suggestions.